# Can't overwrite custom VS CODE theme (Material Theme) tokens (tokenColorCustomizations)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like Material Theme in VS Code, however I don't like keywords (function, if, else, return etc) color. I'm trying to overwrite it using example they provide, but it doesn't work

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Material Theme]": {
        "keywords": "#251977"
    }
}
```

I tried reloading the page - didn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: when I add your setting I get a very dark blue on dark grey for keywords

Comment: @rioV8 it's not working for me... I'm trying to figure out what is the problem

Comment: which `settings.json` are you modifying? be sure to try it in the user settings (not the workspace settings)

Comment: @rioV8 it was actually "Material Theme Darker"... so I figured it out... Now I'm trying to target a specific keyword i.e. for, return, import, export... Don you know by any chance how can I do that ?

Comment: you need to add additional TextMate scope rules to split the keywords indifferent groups and then add TextMate color scope to your  `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`